# Using the solr search results for futher processing

Tags: solr

If am not wrong with the basic understanding of how Solr works, the ResponseWriters write the results of current query in the format specified in the writer type(wt) field of the query. Is the response written physically stored somewhere so that i can use it for further processing? Or can I redirect the response to a file of my choice by specifying the path in the response writers? I am planning on using Solr as an IR tool. Am a newbie to Solr sorry if i sound ignorant.

Comment: Solr is intended to be used as a web service, so the answers to your questions are highly dependent on the platform and tools you are using.  Solr itself can't redirect to a file, but of course any software talking to Solr can do so.

Comment: @tarleb, Thanks for the quick response. I've developed a code in java that would process a text file. My intent is to dump the content from Solr to that text file for further processing. Which part of the Solr code i've to tweak so as to achieve the goal?

Comment: You could write your own `ResponseWriter` to write to a file and configure Solr to use that writer via the `queryResponseWriter` option in solrconfig.xml.  However, by far the simpler method would be to just get the JSON or XML response from Solr's HTTP interface and store the response to a file.  One can use any language to do that or even do it manually using any browser.

Comment: Thanks a ton.. That helped